# xCode dynamically add fields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

i am very new to iOS development, i am stuck with issue here and cant find solution anywhere else.

I need to dynamically generate fields on profileDetailViewController.m which is type of UIViewController,

Fields I want on view are stored in **Array** which looks like this,

```
Array:(
        {
        fieldName = Full Name;
        value = Neil G.;
    },
        {
        fieldName = Aboutn me;
        value = "a web dev..";
    },
        {
        fieldName = State;
        value = Colorado;
    },
        {
        fieldName = City;
        value = Denver;
    },
        {
        fieldName = Website;
        value = "http://google.com";
    },
        {
        fieldName = College University;
        value = "DSU";
    },
        {
        fieldName = Graduation Year;
        value = 2011;
    }
)
```

I am just trying to make it like contacts in IPhone, 
Initially load page as display mode with edit button, so when Edit mode it should turn into form with editable fields. Any good tutorial would be great. I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first grab the size of your array of fields:

`int fieldCount = [Array count];`

then create a wrapperView we will place a scroll view on, since for all we know you will have more fields than you can fit on the screen!

```
UIView *wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubView:wrapperView];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:wrapperView.frame];
[wrapperView addSubView:scrollView];
```

Now I'm going to just add some labels for the purposes here, but you could easily make them buttons or what have you. I will have them be 21 height with a 10 pixel space in between.

So now we need to set the `contentSize` of the scrollView,

```
double heightNeeded = 0;
heightNeeded = fieldCount * 31;
if(heightNeeded < scrollView.frame.size.height){
    heightNeeded = scrollView.frame.size.height;
}
```

Now we can tell the scrollView how large it content size needs to be, and then add all the labels. I am going to assume your array is filled with objects called Details which have a fieldName and a Value, because you didn't really specify.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,heightNeeded)];
int currentY = 0;
for(Details *thisDetail in Array){
   UILabel *thisLabel = [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,currentY,scrollView.frame.size.width,21)];
    [thisLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    thisLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    UILabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",thisDetail.fieldName,thisDetail.Value];
    [thisLabel sizeToFit];
    [scrollView addSubView thisLabel];
    currentY = currentY + thisLabel.frame.origin.y + thisLabel.frame.size.height + 10;
 }
```

not sure if you want them to be labels like this, but that is easily changed. There may be a few more things, like implementing UIScrollViewDelegate and then `scrollView.delegate = self` somewhere, but I'm not sure. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks user1458968, your solution was perfect.. second thing, i am trying to make fields to toggle from display to editable, so when edit button pressed it should work as form.. just like iPhone contacts.. is there any direct way or i just have to add textFields instead of labels. thanks again..

Comment: Yeah man, I would make them UITextFields instead and toggle `userInteractionEnabled` or whatever it's called. Consider changing the background color to gray or something when they're not editable, not sure if it's apparent and I'm not in front of my computer with xCode right now

Comment: Am I wrong, or could u get the 'heightNeeded' by calculating 'fieldCount * 31'? So you don't need a for loop for adding 31 fieldCount-times.